# Get max value under a set of conditions

Tags: r, max, selection

I want to make a new column named `max distance`, where I want to display the maximum distance from column `Distance (km)`. However, I want to make my dataframe shorter by selecting in the columns `Season` and `Transmitter`. In order words: every unique `Transmitter` name should get a max distance under the unique season values. For example: Transmitter `A69-1602-59769` should get a max distance value under Winter1, Spawn1, Forage, Winter2 and Spawn2, ultimately for every unique Transmitter. Unfortunately, my dataset is pretty large and not all unique functions are visible. The unique values of `Season` are shown below:

[1] "Winter1" "Spawn1"  "Forage"  "Winter2" "Spawn2"

How can I make this happen?

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 
18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18212, 18212, 18212, 
18212, 18212, 18212, 18212, 18212, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 
18213, 18213, 18213, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18214, 
18214, 18214, 18215, 18215, 18215, 18215, 18215, 18215, 18216, 
18216, 18216, 18216, 18216, 18216, 18217, 18217, 18217, 18217, 
18217, 18217, 18217, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18219, 
18219, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18220, 18220, 18220, 
18220, 18220, 18220, 18220, 18220, 18221, 18221, 18221, 18221, 
18221, 18221, 18221, 18222, 18222, 18222, 18222, 18222, 18222, 
18223, 18223, 18223, 18223, 18223, 18223, 18224, 18224, 18224, 
18224, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18225), class = "Date"), Transmitter = c("A69-1602-59769", 
"A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59774", 
"A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59778", 
"A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59777", 
"A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59778", 
"A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59774", 
"A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59771", 
"A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", 
"A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59771", 
"A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59777", 
"A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59772", 
"A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59778", 
"A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59772", 
"A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59773", 
"A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59769", 
"A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59773", 
"A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59772", 
"A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59769", 
"A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59777", 
"A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59778", 
"A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773", 
"A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59778", 
"A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59769", 
"A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773", 
"A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59769", 
"A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59772"), Batch.location = c("Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", 
"Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever"), Season = c("Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", 
"Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1"), Latitude = c(52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 
52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343
), Longitude = c(5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 
5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127), `Distance (km)` = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(716209L, 
1073805L, 1019330L, 812249L, 987220L, 934268L, 840464L, 1156663L, 
1226152L, 795888L, 928943L, 1020561L, 1138203L, 807648L, 855925L, 
966957L, 1234618L, 1085184L, 846794L, 1129076L, 982617L, 955912L, 
1081788L, 1009592L, 814527L, 977839L, 875687L, 842029L, 1102446L, 
1229579L, 1085547L, 1000314L, 807813L, 829339L, 885972L, 984860L, 
1121520L, 1223695L, 706154L, 973168L, 857036L, 922413L, 1131675L, 
1053493L, 1230983L, 947900L, 977889L, 1127631L, 834415L, 1220587L, 
722244L, 1061698L, 911860L, 1157213L, 857431L, 989969L, 724411L, 
1168275L, 837874L, 982503L, 932847L, 769907L, 1232536L, 1032207L, 
846636L, 1209851L, 934974L, 984655L, 746638L, 1229866L, 815912L, 
1020860L, 1203162L, 862968L, 898922L, 972024L, 1227411L, 813436L, 
1037845L, 835304L, 931295L, 1195324L, 981568L, 1049961L, 1225530L, 
839859L, 1141828L, 906338L, 757218L, 969904L, 1026505L, 845489L, 
957888L, 1190118L, 1056091L, 981788L, 751164L, 1229692L, 817813L, 
856978L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272.

Comment: Is your expected output a new frame that contains columns `c("Transmitter", "Season", "max distance")`? BTW, all your distances are 0, so this seems unverifiable here.

Comment: Almost yes, it should contain the columns: Transmitters, Season, Batch.location and max distance. The 0 are correct, in my dataset there are also higher values but I do not know how to display this here.

Comment: What does `Batch.location` have to do with it? You said nothing about that.

Comment: Excuse me that is for later use for plotting purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

```r
aggregate(`Distance (km)` ~ Transmitter + Batch.location + Season, data = dat, FUN = max)
#       Transmitter Batch.location  Season Distance (km)
# 1  A69-1602-59769      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 2  A69-1602-59770      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 3  A69-1602-59771      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 4  A69-1602-59772      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 5  A69-1602-59773      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 6  A69-1602-59774      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 7  A69-1602-59775      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 8  A69-1602-59776      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 9  A69-1602-59777      Den Oever Winter1             0
# 10 A69-1602-59778      Den Oever Winter1             0
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Transmitter, Season, Batch.location) %>%
  summarize(`max distance` = max(`Distance (km)`), .groups = "drop")
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    Transmitter    Season  Batch.location `max distance`
#    <chr>          <chr>   <chr>                   <dbl>
#  1 A69-1602-59769 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
#  2 A69-1602-59770 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
#  3 A69-1602-59771 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
#  4 A69-1602-59772 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
#  5 A69-1602-59773 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
#  6 A69-1602-59774 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
#  7 A69-1602-59775 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
#  8 A69-1602-59776 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
#  9 A69-1602-59777 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
# 10 A69-1602-59778 Winter1 Den Oever                   0
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, .(`max distance` = max(`Distance (km)`)), by = .(Transmitter, Batch.location, Season)]
#        Transmitter Batch.location  Season max distance
#             <char>         <char>  <char>        <num>
#  1: A69-1602-59769      Den Oever Winter1            0
#  2: A69-1602-59776      Den Oever Winter1            0
#  3: A69-1602-59775      Den Oever Winter1            0
#  4: A69-1602-59771      Den Oever Winter1            0
#  5: A69-1602-59774      Den Oever Winter1            0
#  6: A69-1602-59773      Den Oever Winter1            0
#  7: A69-1602-59772      Den Oever Winter1            0
#  8: A69-1602-59777      Den Oever Winter1            0
#  9: A69-1602-59778      Den Oever Winter1            0
# 10: A69-1602-59770      Den Oever Winter1            0
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18211, 18212, 18212, 18212, 18212, 18212, 18212, 18212, 18212, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18213, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18214, 18215, 18215, 18215, 18215, 18215, 18215, 18216, 18216, 18216, 18216, 18216, 18216, 18217, 18217, 18217, 18217, 18217, 18217, 18217, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18218, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18219, 18220, 18220, 18220,  18220, 18220, 18220, 18220, 18220, 18221, 18221, 18221, 18221, 18221, 18221, 18221, 18222, 18222, 18222, 18222, 18222, 18222, 18223, 18223, 18223, 18223, 18223, 18223, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18224, 18225), class = "Date"), Transmitter = c("A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59770", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59771",  "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59776", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773",  "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59778",  "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59778", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59772", "A69-1602-59773", "A69-1602-59777", "A69-1602-59775", "A69-1602-59774", "A69-1602-59769", "A69-1602-59778",  "A69-1602-59771", "A69-1602-59772"), Batch.location = c("Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever",  "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever",  "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever", "Den Oever"), Season = c("Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1",  "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1",  "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1", "Winter1"), Latitude = c(52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343,  52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343,  52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343, 52.92343), Longitude = c(5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127,  5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127,  5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127, 5.04127), "Distance (km)" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(716209L, 1073805L, 1019330L, 812249L, 987220L, 934268L, 840464L, 1156663L, 1226152L, 795888L, 928943L, 1020561L, 1138203L, 807648L, 855925L, 966957L, 1234618L, 1085184L, 846794L, 1129076L, 982617L, 955912L, 1081788L, 1009592L, 814527L, 977839L, 875687L, 842029L, 1102446L, 1229579L, 1085547L, 1000314L, 807813L, 829339L, 885972L,  984860L, 1121520L, 1223695L, 706154L, 973168L, 857036L, 922413L, 1131675L, 1053493L, 1230983L, 947900L, 977889L, 1127631L, 834415L, 1220587L, 722244L, 1061698L, 911860L, 1157213L, 857431L, 989969L, 724411L, 1168275L, 837874L, 982503L, 932847L, 769907L, 1232536L, 1032207L, 846636L, 1209851L, 934974L, 984655L, 746638L, 1229866L, 815912L, 1020860L, 1203162L, 862968L, 898922L, 972024L, 1227411L, 813436L, 1037845L, 835304L, 931295L, 1195324L, 981568L, 1049961L, 1225530L, 839859L, 1141828L, 906338L, 757218L,  969904L, 1026505L, 845489L, 957888L, 1190118L, 1056091L, 981788L, 751164L, 1229692L, 817813L, 856978L), class = "data.frame")
```